# DBML to SQL script?

Tags: linq, dbml

Initially I created database tables and generated DBML class file using Database. (LINQ).

But due to system crash, I lost my database instance ( around 20 tables ) and I want to get it back. ( atlest schema )

Is there any tool/ way to generate SQL  from DBML file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a way to do it on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx). I bit citation:

> there is enough information about the relational database that you can
>   create a new instance of the database using the
>   DataContext.CreateDatabase method.

```
YourDbContext db = new YourDbContext ("c:\\yourDbFile.mdf");
db.CreateDatabase();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This helps me.